# VirtualDub filter framebuffer - freeing memory

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, virtualdub

I am writing a VirtualDub filter, which requires a separate frame buffer for intermediate image processing between fa->src.data and fa->dst.data (.data is essentially a pointer to Pixel data).

I create a char pointer to the above using this:

```
/* Pointers to source and destination frame stores */
char *src = (char *)fa->src.data;
char *dst = (char *)fa->dst.data;

/* Image width and height */
int w = fa->src.w*sizeof(Pixel32);
int h = fa->src.h*sizeof(Pixel32);
```

This then allows me to copy data from source frame to destination frame, line by line:

```
memcpy(dst,src,w);
```

Now I would like to have an intermediate buffer that I can copy from *dst to buffer, then from buffer to *src. How can I do that?

I tried several things with varying degrees of success.

```
/* Define and initialise char array with malloc */
char *buf = (char*)malloc(w*h);
```

Then:

```
memcpy(buf,src,w); /* copy to buffer */
memcpy(dst,buf,w); /* copy from buffer to dst */
```

Most of the time, this seems to work. However, after a short while I get "An out-of-bounds memory access (access violation) occurred in module ". The issue is that I seem to run out of system memory (VirtualDub takes ALL the available memory after a while).

Do I need to free the buffer? Seems odd, since it is initialised every frame. How can I free it?

I tried free(dstbuf) and free(&dstbuf) but I am getting "Debug Assertion Failed" error at runtime, expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)... with not much else.

Any ideas?

Comment: free the same buf as you allocate

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by allocating memory only once per run. There's no reason to allocate memory for each frame, since I only need to hold one frame at a time.